# Background images and colors not changing in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have some pretty simple javascript built that works fine in Chrome. However, there are a couple of things that aren't working in IE and Firefox. Here is the code:

```
function updateColors(){
    ChangeCSSRule('background-color',color,2);
    ChangeCSSRule('color',textcolor,0);
    ChangeCSSRule('color',textcolor,1);
    ChangeCSSRule('background-image','url(borders/r_edge_'+imgcolor+'.png)',3);
    ChangeCSSRule('background-image','url(borders/l_edge_'+imgcolor+'.png)',4);
    ChangeCSSRule('background-image','url(borders/t_edge_'+imgcolor+'.png)',5);
    ChangeCSSRule('background-image','url(borders/b_edge_'+imgcolor+'.png)',6); 
}   

function ChangeCSSRule(xElement, xValue, value){
    var strCSS = 'cssRules';
    if(document.all){
        strCSS = 'rules';
    }
    document.styleSheets[0][strCSS][value].style[xElement] = xValue;
}
```

And here is the style sheet:

```
.firstName {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 0px; 
}
.lastName {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-wrap: none;
   margin: 0px;
}
.bg {
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
.r_edge {
   background-image: url(borders/r_edge_white.png); 
   background-repeat: repeat-y;     
}
.l_edge {
   background-image: url(borders/l_edge_white.png); 
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.t_edge {
   background-image: url(borders/t_edge_white.png); 
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.b_edge {
   background-image: url(borders/b_edge_white.png); 
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.right {
   text-align: right;
}
```

I have put asterisks next to the few lines that aren't working. The weird part is that the ChangeCSSRule function works on the two "color" lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post only the minimum code required to understand your question. No one wants to be greeted at the door by this wall of text.

Comment: You should post only as much code as is necessary to demonstrate/reproduce the problem -- not more, and not less. Ideally, you could post an example on http://jsfiddle.net (but this isn't necessary and sometimes is not possible for certain classes of problems).

Answer (score 5):

When changing CSS attributes in javascript you need to camel-case them, for instance: background-color becomes backgroundColor and background-image becomes backgroundImage.

Comment: This works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. However, not in IE versions before 9. It seems that the entire ChangeCSSRule function doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you actually change your code to camel case the attributes to see if they worked in IE < 9?